# Pancakeswaps Router 2.0 swapExactTokensForTokens fails. No errors

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

Please tell me why this tx is failed?

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xa5d5df02bfd7ea6f69664f3f404973e572fca20b35e0c5d27fd74aea0fe3b5cf

```
Tx Data:
0   amountIn    uint256 66350193942313470867
1   amountOutMin    uint256 0
2   path    address[]   27ae27110350b98d564b9a3eed31baebc82d878d
f21768ccbc73ea5b6fd3c687208a7c2def2d966e
3   to  address 594efbe5a71a10a958d812b4c65f3dfa60922a15
4   deadline    uint256 9999999999999999
```

The pair exists. Tokens are approved. Is this related to some fees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that router's [factory](https://bscscan.com/address/0xbcfccbde45ce874adcb698cc183debcf17952812#readContract) there isn't such token pair (`27ae27110350b98d564b9a3eed31baebc82d878d` and `f21768ccbc73ea5b6fd3c687208a7c2def2d966e`).

Comment: yes, indeed. this is true. But what happened here: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdb763b0ab45ddb0c4c80544074ac915fa698f40691648abf4674a09d75ff350c
No errors from router. Pair exists

Comment: Factory: 0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73. No success  no errors. Error on first transfer as I understand.  When we transfer bnb

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk From the [transaction trace](https://bscscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0xdb763b0ab45ddb0c4c80544074ac915fa698f40691648abf4674a09d75ff350c&type=gethtrace2) one of the internal transactions has run out of gas.